# Docker error at higher core counts on a multi core machine

Tags: docker

I am running a Centos Container using docker on a RHEL 65 machine. I am trying to run an MPI application (MILC) on 16 cores.

My server has 20 cores and 128 GB of memory.

My application runs fine until 15 cores but fails with the `APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Bus error (signal 7)` error when using 16 cores and up. At 16 cores and up these are the messages I see in the logs.

```
Jul 16 11:29:17 localhost abrt[100668]: Can't open /proc/413/status: No such file or directory
Jul 16 11:29:17 localhost abrt[100669]: Can't open /proc/414/status: No such file or directory
Jul 16 11:29:17 localhost abrt[100670]: Can't open /proc/417/status: No such file or directory
```

A few details on the container:

- kernel 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64
- Official centos from docker hub
- Started container as:
  `docker run -t -i -c 20 -m 125g --name=test --net=host centos /bin/bash`

I would greatly appreciate any and all feedback regarding this. Please do let me know if I can provide any further information.

Regards

Comment: This looks more like a question about system administration than about programming; it might be better placed on ServerFault than here.

Comment: Thank you. Will post there.